# SQL Query based on value of a different row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to query data from multiple tables but cannot seem to achieve this type of JOIN. For example, I have one table with contains products, and a wp_usermeta table with various user meta data:

Products Table

```
Serial #     Product
---------------------
0001         A
0002         B
0003         C
```

wp_usermeta (simplified)

```
User ID     Key         Value
--------------------------------
1           Serials     0001
1           Company     Company A
2           Serials     0001
2           Company     Company B
3           Serials     0001
3           Company     Company C
```

I need to get the Company name based on the serial numbers they own, such as:

```
Serial #      Company
-------------------------
0001          Company A
0002          Company B
0003          Company C
```

I've been able to retrieve the User ID based on serial number with a simple join query, but I dont know where to go from there.

`SELECT products.serial_number, wp_usermeta.user_id FROM products LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON products.serial_number = wp_usermeta.meta_value`

Comment: You will find that metadata tables (those laid out as yours with Entity, Attribute and Value are the more difficult tables to search through), unfortunately many content management systems (like Wordpress) are full of them. In best practice they are better avoided in practical use.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the `products` table has to do with the results you need.

One method is a "simple" self-join:

```
SELECT p.value as serial_number, c.value as Company.user_id
FROM wp_usermeta p JOIN
     wp_usermeta c
     ON p.user = c.user AND
        p.key = 'Serials' AND
        c.key = 'Company';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 joins on wp_usermeta like this:

```
SELECT Products.Serial, w2.Value AS Company 
FROM Products
# Detect User Id by serial number
JOIN wp_usermeta w1 ON w1.Key = 'Serials' 
    AND w1.Value = Products.Serial
# And select company by detected User Id
JOIN wp_usermeta w2 ON w2.Key = 'Company'
    AND w2.User = w1.User
```